# HTTP 500 response using v1 linkedin companies shares api

Tags: php, linkedin-api, http-error

It's been 2 days that trying to post content through LinkedIn API for a specific company page is failing with "Internal service error". Strangely, it only happens to this specific company page (id: 10684715) not any other company pages we post to! the code is in php. I have checked the company page to see if there is any information that helps and could find nothing. Also, posting the same content directly to LinkedIn works but not through API. Same code and similar requests worked previously. Moreover, sharing same content to another company page works! but not on this specific company page! anyone has any idea why?

endpoint:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/10684715/shares
```

header:

```
Connection: Keep-Alive,
x-li-format: json,
Authorization: Bearer ****,
Content-Type: application/json,
Content-Length: ****,
```

post data:

```
{
    "visibility": "anyone",
    "comment": "Your inner world is SO POWERFUL in creating the life that you desire. Awareness of your thoughts and emotions gives you the ability to change them to ones that serve your highest good. #Blisspot #Findyourblisspot
https://www.blisspot.com/albums/photo/view/album_id/220/photo_id/1204/type/creation_date/count/209/category_id/0/title/Recent+Photos/offset/1",
    "content": {
         "submitted-url": "https://www.blisspot.com/albums/photo/view/album_id/220/photo_id/1204/type/creation_date/count/209/category_id/0/title/Recent+Photos/offset/1",
         "title": "",
         "description": " "
    }
}
```

the response:

```
{
    "errorCode": 0,
    "message": "Internal service error",
    "requestId": "F6FH1FP3HI",
    "status": 500,
    "timestamp": 1516752029921
}
```

Comment: I've not used the LinkedIn API before, so am making some general suggestions. Is the API token authorised to write to that page? Are there any page settings that might prevent API write requests?

Comment: Yes, we're using an authorised token and it was working before. But, even renewing the token didn't help. I don't know about the second part. I looked at the admin of the company page and didn't find anything related. I also checked the users account -> privacy and setting -> partners and services -> permitted services and I can see that our app is listed there. Don't really know why this stopped working suddenly.

Comment: @MaryamTalebi We're seeing a similar issue with sending to shares to personal profile. Since Monday evening, we get an "Internal service error", but the share still appears on the user's profile. Are you seeing similar behavior when you get the error message?

Comment: Sorry for the useless "me too" response, but we're seeing this as well, on a number of different accounts and pages. Can't find a common thread. Worse, it seems like LinkedIn actually posts the share occasionally, even though it responds with a 500.

Comment: @hundredwatt I double checked and you're right. They are getting posted but we're getting 500!!

Comment: I have the same issue with timeline posts(posts successful). For page/company posts, fails with  'Internal error', also failed to post. I use Java.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an intermittent issue with the #linkedin API v2. For the clients that are getting 500 errors, when you do page searches via the API those pages don't even exist apparently.

But, if you run the same search via v1 it comes up, and you can post using the v1 API.

What is strange is that it will suddenly start working again after a few days. Same calls, same tokens.

I have reached out to their developers for help, but they just reply to post here. Let's hope that they are catching and debugging these 500 errors.

But so far the changes in the v2 API are very welcome, apart from the 500 bugs

Comment: Gregory, are you able to provide some examples of the issues you're getting and what end-points you're hitting. Also is there a question you had, or did you just want to post a notice?

Comment: I was let people know that we'd seen similar and had raised it as an issue. This was the closest and I wanted to let people know what we'd done to resolve it for now till we can reliably use the new APIs. In terms of examples, no because the two clients it happened to have started working again.

Comment: So sorry, I was reviewing the post and I assumed this was the question, not a response. Ignore me - what a silly mistake.

Comment: All good. Was a wordy response too. And was a bit of both. TBH, I want LinkedIn to pay attention and be a bit more open about their APIs

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still has this issue, after 3 days it got fixed itself. Apparently, it was due to an update on some pages on LinkedIn side and after a couple of days they fixed it.

**UPDATE:** The issue is fixed for the pages that had issue before .But, now it's happening to some other pages we're handling!!!