# Linkedin API v1 - Internal API server error on "list all companies that the member is an administrator of" call

Tags: linkedin-api

Since yesterday, when I call https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies?format=json&count=5&start=1&is-company-admin=true (or any other combination of this API) I always get the same error response (Internal API server error):

```
{
    "error": "Request Error: Internal API server error. Raw Response: Array
    (
        [errorCode] => 0
        [message] => Internal API server error  
        [requestId] => TJM0TA4N29  
        [status] => 500
        [timestamp] => 1518595727489
    )"
}
```

The problem seems to be on Linkedin side.
Any idea or solution?

Comment: After a series of further tests (i used count=1 to have one company in any response) the problem is related to a single company.
With this specific page all API return the same error (Internal API server error). I verify from Linkedin webstite and I'm an administrator and the page  doesn't show any strangeness.

Comment: This was a temporary issue with LinkedIn's API server that appears to have been resolved over the weekend. A number of corroborating reports were posted here & deleted for "not really answering the question" - hopefully this comment sticks around, as SO is where the LinkedIn Developer site directs users for troubleshooting and typically dominates search results for LinkedIn API issues.

Comment: I confirm that the LinkedIn's API server error was resolved saturday

Answer (score 0):

We've been having some issues with the v2 API that aren't dissimilar (we're in the marketing program so have access to the  v2 APIs):
[HTTP 500 response using v1 linkedin companies shares api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48413350/http-500-response-using-v1-linkedin-companies-shares-api/49020035#49020035)

It's so odd because it's only some clients and their pages don't even exist when you query them via the v2 API. But they are there for v1.

Then suddenly one client would be fixed and working fine again, only for it to happen to a different client a bit later. Very odd.

Our current solution is to use both APIs but v1 predominately, and v2 when we need to do something that v1 doesn't support.

Have you had this re-occur? Assume it's related to the new APIs