# HTTP 500 response using v1 linkedin companies api

Tags: linkedin-api, http-error

trying to get company's basic info through API breaks giving 500 resp code. trying another company token just works! Is this the same issue that's been happening for some company pages for awhile now?

endpoint

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies:(id,name,universal-name,logo-url,company-type,industries)?format=json&is-company-admin=true
```

header:

```
Authorization: Bearer ****,
```

response:

```
{
    "errorCode": 0,
    "message": "Internal API server error",
    "requestId": "JF1034IJDZ",
    "status": 500,
    "timestamp": 1523938854642
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48413350/http-500-response-using-v1-linkedin-companies-shares-api)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP 500 response using v1 linkedin companies shares api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48413350/http-500-response-using-v1-linkedin-companies-shares-api)

Comment: Apart from a possible duplicate mentioned above, it is also direct issue related with LinkedIn API itself. We experienced this few days ago with various requests and endpoints towards LinkedIn API, and response was same. Few hours later, API wasn't throwing this error

Comment: @niklaz the other question is asked by myself as well. Unfortunately LinkeIn doesn't have any support. It is mentioned in they're docs that issues should be asked on StackOverflow with these tags. And this has been going on for a few months on our side now! sorry but I didn't have any other option but to ask again here, so they may look at it!

Comment: It may be related to those other issues, but it's not duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the same problem.

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies:(id,name,universal-name,logo-url,square-logo-url)?is-company-admin=true&format=json
```

The request works normally if you don't include field names:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies?is-company-admin=true&format=json
```

They've clearly broken the ability to pass field names to the /companies endpoint.